# Python Error (Importing Module)

Tags: python

I have installed `cufflinks` using

```
pip install however
```

when I try to import it is says

```
No module named 'cufflinks'
```

What can I do?

PS python 3.6

Comment: did you restart your ide/app/terminal ?

Comment: Are you using an IDE or plain terminal to run the code? Do you have a virtual environment or you are using global environment? Most probably your Python interpreter is not where your environment is.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should use pip3 install for python 3.6. Than check if module cufflinks is added to your sys.path.

Comment: Nah bad answer. You are complicating the matter unnecessarily.